# Update view controller of a data update in model

Tags: ios

How can I notify the view controller of a new update in the model without using notifications, delegates or KVO? I was asked in an interview if I can use blocks to notify my view controller of an update? Can you please give me an example of how I would use blocks to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of discussion written on the subject you're asking about (choosing between delegation, notifications, observation, and blocks). I'll see if I can sum up why and how to use blocks quickly:

You would use a block when there is only one or two events to tell an observer / calling object about. An example from the iOS library is in the `NSURLSessionDataTask` class - it has a method:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler
```

Since there are only a limited amount of things that could happen on a network call (it goes through successfully or it fails), a block is used.

On the other hand, you might use delegation when there are a lot of different events to notify an observer / delegate of. A good example is `UITextField` - a text field in iOS can beginEditing, endEditing, change characters in the field, clear, return, etc. It doesn't make a ton of sense to overload a block with all the different options. Thus, delegation is used so that the delegate can choose which events it cares to know about / be updated on, and skip the others.

To use this on your model, you might, have a model method that looks like this, for example:

`- (void) saveObject:(NSObject*)object completionHandler:(void (^) (BOOL success, NSError *error))completionHandler`

This would update an object you pass in and then run the block you pass in when it finishes. Within that block, you can access the success flag as well as a possible error. You can call this directly from your view controller and use variables defined within said view controller.

The whole debate is really more an art form than an exact science. If you'd like to read more about this, feel free to take a look at some posts like the following:

http://stablekernel.com/blog/blocks-or-delegates/
http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/

Answer (score 0):

ReactiveCocoa is another possible solution. ReactiveCocoa is a popular framework that works in a similar way to KVO but uses blocks instead.

Checkout the introduction section on their github page for a simple example:

https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#introduction

There are also some good tutorials on the topic:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/62699/reactivecocoa-tutorial-pt1

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I believe ReactiveCocoa uses KVO behind the scenes